# How to change console window style at runtime?

Tags: c++, hwnd, window-handles

I'm making a game in console application and I want to prevent user resizing and maximizing window. How can I do this using HWND?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with an HWND. You're going to need to use the [console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: When you searched the internet for "msdn c++ prevent window closing API", what showed up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution. This code will disable window Size and Maximize box:

```
HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
```