# Disable resizing for python console application in Windows

Tags: python, windows, console

Here is a code to disable resizing using c++

[How to change console window style at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172595/how-to-change-console-window-style-at-runtime)

```
HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
```

However, I want to use this code in python. It's my effort so far:

```
def fix_borders():
    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
    hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
    kernel32.SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 
            kernel32.GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX)
```

However, SetWindowLong isn't recognized and I don't know how to import other constants...

Comment: With ctypes you're working at the ABI level, so you need to know the DLL name and function name that compiled API code uses. If you look up the docs for `SetWindowLong`, you'll see that it's outdated and the API uses `SetWindowLongPtr` instead. Next, note that it comes in a byte-string "A" version and a wide-character string "W" version. By default ctypes passes Python 3.x strings as wide-character strings, so choose the "W" version. For the DLL to use, the docs tell you that it's "user32.dll", so use `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)` and `user32.SetWindowLongPtrW`.

Comment: Define the constants from the docs or header files. See [`SetWindowLongPtrW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) and [Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles).

Comment: That said, you should not modify the console window unless the current process owns it. Given python.exe is often launched by py[w].exe, you can also modify the console if the parent process is "py[w].exe" and it owns the console window. Otherwise it's not your window to modify, and doing so would be rude and annoying behavior.

Comment: Check window ownership via [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid). Check the parent process ID via `os.getppid()`, and check if it's "py[w].exe" via [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) (with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access) and [`QueryFullProcessImageNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew).

Comment: Thank you very much! I just thought to disable resizing at the start of my application and enable it at the end of it. However, you say that it can affect any other instance of the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it still utilizing ctypes and using win32api (definitely not the most elegant solution though):

```
def lock_resize():
    while True:
        STDOUT = -11

        hdl = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STDOUT)
        rect = ct.wintypes.SMALL_RECT(0, 50, 50, 80) # (left, top, right, bottom)
        windll.kernel32.SetConsoleWindowInfo(hdl, True, byref(rect))
    
_thread.start_new_thread(lock_resize,()) #using the _thread module to keep everything else running
```